# Are there PPAD-complete puzzles?

Tags: puzzles, board-games, ppad

Most puzzles that you can buy are in P, NP-complete (like Sudoku) or PSPACE-complete (like Sokoban), at least if you scale them up.
Are there any *natural* puzzles that are PPAD-complete?
What about other similar classes, like PPA, PPADS etc?

If we don't insist on natural, then of course practically any PPAD-complete problem would be a puzzle, just during the puzzle you would need to run the some Turing machine a couple of times.
What I have in mind would be for example finding [another Hamiltonian cycle](https://kintali.wordpress.com/2009/07/25/finding-a-second-hamilton-circuit/) in a cubic graph, which is known to be in PPA, just now known to be complete.

Answer (score 2):

In the [most authoritative reference](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~kintali/ppad.html) on PPAD-complete problems, there is no PPAD-complete puzzle mentioned.

Comment: The most recent archived version of the page: https://web.archive.org/web/20160816142056/http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~kintali/ppad.html